# How to filter the CRM data source as Source to pick up the Last Modified Records after Each Run of Pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am Integrating from CRM to Azure SQL DB but I want to set the Net Change as `Last ModifiedOn`. This will help to update/insert only those records modified since the previous run. I am trying to fetch the Latest modified on date-time from SQL but  I am unable to pass it Fetch XML query for CRM Source. The Query I am using is as follows:

```xml
    <fetch>
      <entity name="msdyn_project">
        <all-attributes />

        <filter type="and">
          <condition attribute="modifiedon" operator="on-or-after" 
    value="@{activity(\'LookupOldWaterMarkactivity\').output.firstRow.Prop_0}"/>

        </filter>
      </entity>
    </fetch>
```

Please suggest if there is some other workaround for this.

Comment: Hi,any progress here?

Comment: hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: This is not helping as it gives Syntax Error.

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience,you can't set `@{activity(...)}` in the Fetch XML query SQL directly.If you want to use `@{activity(...)}`,it belongs to dynamic content:

[image]

So,you could try to use `@cancat` to complete the query SQL:

```
@concat(
'<fetch><entity name="">.....<condition attribute="modifiedon" operator="on-or-after"  value=',
@{activity("LookupOldWaterMarkactivity").output.firstRow.Prop_0, 
'/>....</fetch>')
```

Comment: If the filter query results to >5000 records, is pagination needed to get the remaining records?